# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.....'

Tags: android, facebook, push-notification

I receive these errors when I try to add  Facebook in app notification library

```
    compile 'com.facebook.android:notifications:1.0.2'
```

> Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>   Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

compile sdk version is 22   ,    build Tools Version is 23.0.2.
push notifications libray - https://github.com/facebook/FBNotifications

I know if I change  compile sdk version to 23   this error  will go away. but on my project  I using  some  methods that were deprecated on version 23  its not possible at the moment to change compile sdk version to 23.

Is there any other method to  make this error go away

Comment: Deprecated methods still work, what SDK you compile with doesn't change that.

Comment: Have you solved it yet? If yes please answer the question

Answer (score 1):

There's no solution other than to change your compile SDK version to 23 or not use that library. If a library is built against a higher SDK (and requires new APIs from that SDK), then your app must also build against the higher SDK.

Per the [Picking your compileSdkVersion blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd):

> It should be emphasized that **changing your compileSdkVersion does not change runtime behavior.** While new compiler warnings/errors may be present when changing your compileSdkVersion, your compileSdkVersion is not included in your APK: it is purely used at compile time.

It is *targetSdkVersion* that potentially changes the behavior of your app is what you should make sure to test before incrementing.